# Could not call setState for React 16 when testing with enzyme 3

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jsdom

I just upgraded enzyme 3 and react 16. My tests were working before. Now it's failing. Below is the description.

My app is using:

```
react@16.2.0
jsdome@^11.10.0
enzyme@^3.3.0
```

And this is my test:

```
it('should show real numbers on click', () => {
    // at beginning, it shows some masked value
    expect(wrapper).to.contain
        .text(MASKED);
    // trying to do a click on the element
    let maskedElem = wrapper.find('.masked');
    maskedElem.prop('onClick')();

    // expecting it to have a new value
    expect(wrapper).to.contain
        .text(VALUE);
});
```

And it's failing for `maskedElem.prop('onClick')();`.

This is the error stack.

```
 Error: An error was thrown inside one of your components, but React doesn't know what it was. This is likely due to browser flakiness. React does its best to preserve the "Pause on exceptions" behavior of the DevTools, which requires some DEV-mode only tricks. It's possible that these don't work in your browser. Try triggering the error in production mode, or switching to a modern browser. If you suspect that this is actually an issue with React, please file an issue.
  at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:586:19)
  at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:438:27)
  at renderRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:10366:7)
```

This is the component that I'm testing.

```
class Phone extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            clicked: false
        };
    }

    onClick() {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            clicked: true
        })
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.clicked) {
            return (
                <span>{this.props.value}</span>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <span onClick = {() => this.onClick()}
                className='masked'>
                    {MASKED}
                </span>
            );

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the `onClick` function directly you can use the enzyme API function [`simulate()`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.md) to activate your click events

```
// trying to do a click on the element
let maskedElem = wrapper.find('.masked');
maskedElem.simulate('click);
```

Comment: tried. Still the same error: Error: An error was thrown inside one of your components, but React doesn't know what it was. This is likely due to browser flakiness. React does its best to preserve the "Pause on exceptions" behavior of the DevTools, which requires some DEV-mode only tricks. It's possible that these don't work in your browser. Try triggering the error in production mode, or switching to a modern browser. If you suspect that this is actually an issue with React, please file an issue.

Comment: This suggests it isn't your tests which are breaking, but something in your component

Comment: The error could be related to how you are instantiating your tests. Could you post the part in your tests that creates the `wrapper` element?

Comment: I'm still having errors upgrading to react 16, enzyme 3 and jsdom. However I can confirm this error was due to the configuration of jsdom. Particularly, it was because HTMLElement was not available in the global scope with jsdom ( I was using node-jsdom before)